# Find complicated substring with wildcards Python

Tags: python, string, wildcard

I am trying to locate the position of an expression in a long string. The expression works as follows. It is given by any element of list1, followed by wildcard of 1 to 5 words (separated by spaces) and followed by any element of list2. For example:

```
list1=["a","b"], list2=["c","d"]
text = "bla a tx fg hg gfgf tzt zt blaa  a  bli blubb d  muh meh  muh d"
```

should return "37" since that is where the expression ("a  bli blubb d") is found. I looked into regex wildcards, but I  struggle to put that together with different elements of the lists and also the variable length of the wild cards.

Appreciate any advice!

Comment: Is 'a blaa  a  bli blubb d' also a valid result?

Comment: yeah I see your point, that example was choosen poorly, I  therefore edited it. This pattern would not occur in the text naturally...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could construct a regex:

```
import re

pref=["a","b"]
suff=["c","d"]

# the pattern is dynamically constructed from your pref and suff lists.
patt = r"(?:\W|^)((?:" + '|'.join(pref) + r")(?: +[^ ]+){1,5} +(?:" + '|'.join(suff) + r"))(?:\W|$)"

text = "bla a tx fg hg gfgf tzt zt blaa  a  bli blubb d  muh meh  muh d"

print(patt)

for k in re.findall(patt,text):
    print(k, "\n", text.index(k))
```

Output:

```
(?:\W|^)((?:a|b)(?: +[^ ]+){1,5} +(?:c|d))(?:\W|$)  # pattern
a  bli blubb d                                      # found text
33                                                  # position (your 37 is wrong btw.)
```

Fair warning: this is not a very robust approach.

The regex is something like:

```
Either start of line or non-text character (not captured) followed by
one of your prefs. followed by 1-n spaces, followed by 1-5 non-space things that 
are seperated by 1-n spaces, followed by something from suff followed
by (non captured non-Word-Character or end of line)
```

For a demo and a more complete description of the assembled regex: see https://regex101.com/r/WHZfr9/1

Comment: Wow you beat me. I had an almost identical solution! A few minor differences, my final output pattern looks like `(\W+|^)((a|b)\W+(\w+\W+){1,5}(c|d))(\W+|$)` to allow multiple non-word characters at the beginning at end of line, and I used `for m in pattern.finditer(text): print(m.start(2))` without using non-capturing groups, just grab the 2nd group from the iterator.

Comment: @Davos post it as 2nd way :)

Comment: Nah I don't think it's different enough to warrant more than a comment :)